# Log in script giving blank screen

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I have a log in script, when the form redirects it is simply showing a blank screen, any ideas? I am quite new to PHP so any comments on the script in general would be great.

Many thanks for your help!

```
<?php
session_start(); //must call session_start before using any $_SESSION variables
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
//connect to the database here

require_once('../Connections/PropSuite.php');
mysql_select_db($database_PropSuite, $PropSuite);

$username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$query = "SELECT password, salt
        FROM users
        WHERE username = '$username';";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if(mysql_num_rows($result) < 1) //no such user exists
{
    header('Location: index.php');
    die();
}
$userData = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
$hash = hash('sha256', $userData['salt'] . hash('sha256', $password) );
if($hash != $userData['password']) //incorrect password
{
    header('Location: index.php');
    die();
}
else
{
    validateUser(); //sets the session data for this user
}
//redirect to another page or display "login success" message


?>
```

Comment: What happens if the login data is actually correct? In that case I see no redirection (unless it's in validateUser)

Comment: Oh and a lot of people will tell you to use PDO :-) http://us.php.net/pdo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing the redirect unless you have it in the validateUser() function.
If not you can do either:

```
else
{
   validateUser(); //sets the session data for this user
}
//redirect to another page or display "login success" message
header('Location: your-desired-login-location.php');
die();
?>
```

or..

```
else
{
   validateUser(); //sets the session data for this user
   header('Location: your-desired-login-location.php');
   die();
}
//redirect to another page or display "login success" message

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might have parse errors in your code and you have error reporting turned off.

Solution:

Put this in your header and see the errors, correct them. Remove this when done--it's a nono to have on a production environment.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
```